# How to save the value into database if hit the false statement in php ajax and html if it in array?

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, multidimensional-array

I want to store the display value in a database as a row but only when the statement false. So I created this way to store but not sure about the declaration of each value for the column. I so confused about array and so on. I have this for loop in PHP to display in a table but not sure if this need to convert into an array.

```
      <?php 
      for($x=$str, $y=0; $y!=($endmo);$x++) {


         if ($w == 1){
            //has code here
          }
         else{

             //it will display value here in table
             $date = $x;
             $a = 8;
             $b = 3;
             $c = 4 ;
            //it will display value here
            //not sure if need to convert into array

           $ts = array("$date", "$a", "$b", "$c");
           $var = json_encode($ts);
           }
          $y++;
       }
       ?>
```

The idea is I just want to store the else value statement only. This will store the same value of a, b and c but different date when rendering this and this will save in row but we will save the value for each in a different column. This is my javascript code :

```
       <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
         var mo = '<?php echo $mo; ?>';
         var yr = '<?php echo $yr; ?>';
         var obj = JSON.parse('<?= $var; ?>');

          //how to get all the value from php above

         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            data: {'date':'date', 'mo': 'mo', 'yr': yr,'a': 'a', 'b': b, 'c': c},
            url: "save.php",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#rdft').html(data);
            }
        });
         }
            </script>
```

In save.php I will use the SQL statement to insert each value into the database.

Comment: if ($w = 1) , shouldnt be that   if ($w == 1) ?

Comment: @FatFreddy sorry i have edit it. It just my summary of my code not the whole. So do you known how i can save the data from the for statement?

Comment: you can store the values directly in the else clause, no need to call a javascript and ajax-handler ?

Comment: @FatFreddy    i have build new coding according to your suggestion. But when i put insert statement it make double in database.